# Can't establish a connection using snowflake-connector-python v1.9

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Asking the following question on behalf of a client)

............

Due to the size of all dependencies snowflake-connector-python is having I had to switch to v1.9 (106Mb total size) and now I'm not able to establish connection, v2.0 is not functioning as well. The only working version is v2.0.1 but it's huge (320Mb total size) comparing to the v1.9.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1131, in validate_by_direct_connection

  self.process_ocsp_response(issuer, cert_id, ocsp_response)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ocsp_asn1crypto.py", line 280, in process_ocsp_response

  tbs_response_data)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ocsp_asn1crypto.py", line 316, in verify_signature

  pubkey = cert.public_key.unwrap().dump()

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asn1crypto/keys.py", line 1065, in unwrap

  'asn1crypto.keys.PublicKeyInfo().unwrap() has been removed, '

asn1crypto._errors.APIException: asn1crypto.keys.PublicKeyInfo().unwrap() has been removed, please use oscrypto.asymmetric.PublicKey().unwrap() instead



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 790, in _request_exec

  auth=SnowflakeAuth(token),

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request

  resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send

  r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send

  timeout=timeout

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen

  body=body, headers=headers)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request

  self._validate_conn(conn)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn

  conn.connect()

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 238, in connect

  ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ssl_wrap_socket.py", line 395, in ssl_wrap_socket_with_ocsp

  ).validate(server_hostname, ret.connection)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ocsp_snowflake.py", line 996, in validate

  return self._validate(hostname, cert_data, telemetry_data, do_retry, no_exception)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1002, in _validate

  cert_data, telemetry_data, hostname, do_retry=do_retry)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1184, in _validate_certificates_sequential

  issuer, subject, telemetry_data, hostname, do_retry=do_retry)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1153, in validate_by_direct_connection

  err = self.verify_fail_open(ex, telemetry_data)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ocsp_snowflake.py", line 1166, in verify_fail_open

  if ex_obj.errno is ER_SERVER_CERTIFICATE_REVOKED:

AttributeError: 'APIException' object has no attribute 'errno'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 640, in _request_exec_wrapper

 **kwargs)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 883, in _request_exec

  raise RetryRequest(err)

snowflake.connector.network.RetryRequest: 'APIException' object has no attribute 'errno'



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/Users/avinogradov/git/crux/step_function/snowflake_update/test.py", line 25, in <module>

  schema=SCHEMA

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/__init__.py", line 33, in Connect

  return SnowflakeConnection(**kwargs)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 187, in __init__

  self.connect(**kwargs)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 484, in connect

  self.__open_connection()

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 700, in __open_connection

  self.__authenticate(auth_instance)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/connection.py", line 931, in __authenticate

  session_parameters=self._session_parameters,

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/auth.py", line 197, in authenticate

  socket_timeout=self._rest._connection.login_timeout)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 521, in _post_request

  _include_retry_params=_include_retry_params)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 600, in fetch

  **kwargs)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 683, in _request_exec_wrapper

  conn, full_url, cause)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 713, in handle_invalid_certificate_error

  u'errno': ER_FAILED_TO_REQUEST,

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 100, in errorhandler_wrapper

  connection.errorhandler(connection, cursor, errorclass, errorvalue)

 File "/Users/avinogradov/.local/share/virtualenvs/snowflake_update-WVrmvZbT/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 73, in default_errorhandler

  done_format_msg=errorvalue.get(u'done_format_msg'))

snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 250003: Failed to execute request: 'APIException' object has no attribute 'errno'
```

............

The client is currently able to get around the issue by using the latest version (2.0.1) but to delete pyarrow and numpy (`pip uninstall pyarrow numpy`) later to reduce dependencies size (these dependencies are used by customers who are on the Private Preview only).

Are there any better recommendations out there?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this is an issue that was fixed in v2.0.1. The older versions of the Python connector are failing while validating the certificate using the recently upgraded package of asn1crypto 1.0.0. The workaround is to use asn1crypt 0.24.0.

```
pip install snowflake-connector-python asn1crypto==0.24.0
```